# Assign a single value to multiple variables in one line in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntactic-sugar

A common way to assign multiple variables is often expressed in programming languages such as C or Python as:

```
a = b = c = value;
```

Is there an equivalent to this in Rust, or do you need to write it out?

```
a = value;
b = value;
c = value;
```

---

Apologies if this is obvious, but all my searches lead to Q&A regarding tuple assignment.

Comment: I don't believe there is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent.  Yes, you have to write multiple assignments, or write a macro which *itself* does multiple assignments.

Comment: Part of the rationale behind this decision is ownership; what would the result of `a = b = c = Vec::new()` be?

Comment: For types which copy by value it could work, nevertheless, I see why it doesn't fit rust so well.

Answer (score 18):

You cannot chain the result of assignments together. However, you *can* assign multiple variables with a single statement.

In a [`let` statement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html#let-statements), you can bind multiple names by using an [irrefutable pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html) on the left side of the assignment:

```
let (a, b) = (1, 2);
```

([Since Rust 1.59](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/02/24/Rust-1.59.0.html#destructuring-assignments), you can also have multiple values in the left side of any assignment, not just `let` statements.)

In order to assign the same value to multiple variables without repeating the value, you can use a [slice pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#slice-patterns) as the left-hand side of the assignment, and an [array expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/array-expr.html#array-expressions) on the right side to repeat the value, if it implements Copy:

```
let value = 42;
let [a, b, c] = [value; 3]; // or: let [mut a, mut b, mut c] = ...
println!("{} {} {}", a, b, c); // prints: 42 42 42
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0269dc8f3a2304eb412d1962bd81d11))

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you can totally do this!

```rust
let a @ b @ c = value;
```

This uses the `@` syntax in patterns, which is used to bind a value to a variable, but keep pattern matching. So this binds `value` to `a` (by copy), and then continues to match the pattern `b @ c`, which binds `value` to `b`, and so on.

But please don't. This is confusing and of little to no benefit over writing multiple statements.

Comment: as confusing as it may seem, i'm purposely writing really confusing code right now for a joke project and this was a great addition, so thanks for posting this :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74878):

```rust
fn main() {
    let [a, b, c] = fill_new_slice(1);
    dbg!(a, b, c);
}

fn fill_new_slice<T: Copy, const N: usize>(value: T) -> [T; N] {
    [value; N]
}
```

```sh
$ cargo run --quiet
[src/main.rs:3] a = 1
[src/main.rs:3] b = 1
[src/main.rs:3] c = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rust, the expression `a = b = c = value;` is the same to `a = (b = (c = value));`

And the `(x = ...)` returns `()`. Then, the first expression is an equivalent of the following:

```rust
c = value;
b = ();
a = ();
```

Note that the expression has a semicolon in the end, but if the expression were in the last line as a function's return like this `a = b = c = value`, the equivalente would be the following:

```rust
c = value;
b = ();
a = () // without the semicolon
```

Comment: "And the `(x = ...)` returns the value of `x`": This is not correct; [assignment returns the unit type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#assignment-expressions) (i.e. `()`). [Rust Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20a%3A%20i32%20%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20a)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20(a%20%3D%202))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20a)%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: You are right. My bad. I updated the answer.

Comment: "In Rust, the expression `a = b = c = value;` is the same to `a = (b = (c = value));`" note that it is true for (probably) all C-like languages; the important part is assignment returning `()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman they are not the same in Rust