# Example of = (assignment) being right-associative

Tags: c, parsing, variable-assignment

Where would the associativity of the `=` assignment operator make a difference in an expression? I thought that the associativity relates to operands that share an operator, but in the case of assignment, how would that work? A few examples that (might) be relevant are:

```
x = 1
x + 2 = y + 3 = z + 5
```

Does this just mean that, in the assignments above, we would have:

```
y + 3 = z + 5
```

Done before, for example:

```
x + 2 = y + 3
```

Or what other scenarios are there where assignment associativity 'matters' ?

Comment: `x + 2 = y + 3` That's not valid C, so it's not a good example. Associativity makes a difference in cases like `int x, y = 0, z = 1; x = y = z;`.

Comment: A better example would be `a = b = c + 1`. You don't want it to mean `a = b` followed by `b = c + 1`.

Comment: In your examples, did you try them out to see if they compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples don't demonstrate anything, because associativity only comes into play when you have several operators with the same precedence (or the same operator) next to each other.

Consider `x = y = 42`, which sets both variables to 42.

Because of right-associativity, it's parsed as `x = (y = 42)`, where `y = ...` returns the new value of `y`, which is 42.

This is why it works. If `=` was left-associative and it was parsed as `(x = y) = 42`, then:

- In C it wouldn't compile at all, because `x = ...` returns an rvalue rather than an lvalue, and those can't be assigned to.
- In C++, where assignments return lvalues, it would work like `x = y; x = 42;`, which is far from being intuitive.

Comment: In C++ `(x = y) = 42;` would work like `x=y, x=42;` wouldn't it?